# How do I manipulate layout of spark/mx components via actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flex4, flash-builder

I know I can create an actionscript loop in a script block that can create an array of objects. The problem is when doing that I don't know how to have those objects interact with the overall layout structure of the mxml document itself. They just default to 0,0.
What If I wanted to arrange a loop of dynamically generated objects inside of a tilegroup and under another dynamically generated item using actionscript for instance? (without individually specifyin x&y)

I need to know how to give them an automatic layout (like horizontal) and then determine where they fall in the order of other objects declared via mxml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add them as elements to the container group of your choice, just use:

```
myVGroup.addElement( myComponent );
```

Inside your loop.  Where `myVGroup` is a VGroup that already exists in your layout.

You may also find this of interest. http://evtimmy.com/2009/06/flowlayout-a-spark-custom-layout-example/

Comment: this is basically right, although every time I try an addChild it doesn't fly. It wants me to use addElement instead.

Comment: I just today found that adding things in a list seems to want to be addChild.. not sure what's going on there/what the difference is.

Comment: The `addElement` method should be used when working with flex containers. Where did you get that information on `addChild` ?  Basically, flex introduces the idea of `elements`, and the regular AS3 displaylist has the 'lower level' (ahem) concept of `child`.